# Do not see Kotlin (Multiplatform Library) option in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

Why don't I see the *Kotlin (Multiplatform Library)* option on creating a new project with IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]

Comment: The option [is available](https://i.imgur.com/CJvFVzG.png) in the current IntelliJ IDEA version. Make sure all the plug-ins [are enabled](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's an old version? What version are you on?